# cast from pointer to integer of different size c

Tags: arrays, pointers, casting, size, assign

I'm having a problem assigning the value of a 2 d array into an int, it gives me the warning "cast from pointer to integer of different size c". Is there any way to assign the value of a 2d array into an int like this:

```
int main (){

    int test[10][10] = {{1}};

    int integer = (int) test[0];

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you can pass a value from an integer 2D array to an int variable.
You've made a minor mistake, you should have wrote it like this:

```
int integer = test[0][0];
```

Just to avoid future errors, you'll need to assign more variables in the other elements in your array else you will receive NULL as value which in some cases stop to program from compiling.

Answer (score 0):

test[0] represents a row. You cannot put an array of integers in integer variable.

> int * integerPointer = (int *) test[0];

would be the correct syntax. Now integerPointer acts as a simple array.

Comment: what if i would want to compare the integer pointer that represents a specific part of the array to another pointer array of another row to determined which number that the row represents is the greatest. How would such a comparison between pointer be made?

Comment: Since 2D arrays get in order memory. You can compare the pointers directly. The pointer value of row 0 will be less then pointer value of row 1 and so on.